# Is it possible to mass enable adaptive subdivision checkbox?

Tags: modeling, scripting, modifiers, shaders, displacement

i would like to assign adaptive subdivision to many meshes. Doing it by hand will take a'lot of time.

It seems transfer modifier does not transfer adaptive settings for now. Maybe it is because the feature itself is new.

Is it possible to somehow enable "adaptive" checkbox on many meshes at once? Maybe some script can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the *adaptive* checkbox(as well as many other options) on multiple objects modifiers, select all the objects and make sure one is active. Then in the objects modifier, hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and select the checkbox.

Comment: I never knew about this feature, thank you!

Comment: This just saved me an hour